# Logo settings in sub-theme not working

Tags: 8

Followed the step to create a subtheme of bootstrap theme. Now, I am not able to see new logo updated, logo is overridden by default logo of bootstrap.

1) Downloaded Bootstrap project (8.x-3.x-dev). Placed the bootstrap folder in theme/contrib

2) Copy the CDN folder from the themes/bootstrap/starterkits folder and pasted in theme/custom folder

3) Changed the cdn folder name to mytheme and all THEMENAME occurrences to mytheme. also the inside file into mytheme.info.yml)

4) Gone to admin/appearance and enabled the mytheme

5) Gone to admin/appearance. Locate the mytheme and click on the Settings link to its right

6) scroll down to the Logo Image Settings section. Uncheck the check box and upload a new logo.

Now the problem is the new logo updated is not visible. It is overridden by theme's default logo.

If I choose other theme such as Bartik 8.0.1 then the logo is visible.

Can anyone please suggest how can I fix this issue?

Comment: I reproduce this issue and you are right. If all you need is to change your logo then upload the file to your theme folder and name it as logo.png. I saw there is no theme specific logo settings.